# Change base model when training google automl custom model

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-automl, machine-translation, google-cloud-translate

Is there a way to change the base model when training a translation custom model in google automl? I was told so, but the drop-down menu in the base model option is blocked and there is a warning that says "All custom translation models are trained based on the Google NMT model".

I want to improve a model that I trained before adding more data and using that previous model as base model.

[image]

Comment: As you note, it’s not possible.  What is your scenario?  To regularly update without retraining everything?  I think Microsoft gives more options here.  But an interesting question would be which MT cloud providers support this (without adaptive).

Comment: I want to reproduce this paper https://storage.googleapis.com/pub-tools-public-publication-data/pdf/120aaefb5f01e824110cfb524ff251db11bf0734.pdf

Comment: This question and answer also suggest that it is or was possible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62141747/is-there-a-way-to-update-a-google-automl-translation-model-without-having-to-cha

Comment: You could write an email to the authors of that paper.  Or try your luck in https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/forums/filteredbylabelpage/board-id/cloud-ai-ml/label-name/cloud%20translation%20api